# Access Viewer HTTP 502

Tags: sitecore-client

When trying to view user that has a lot of roles access via Access Viewer, Sitecore hangs then afterwards return an error message from hosting provider.

This is the screenshot in network tab:
[image]

This is screenshot in Console tab:
[image]

Anybody got an idea as to why this is happening? I don't encounter this problem on my local

Comment: 502 is bad gateway problem. Looks like there is a timeout issue with your request or something like that. Your connecting via cloudfront to your Sitecore server. Have you tried direct connection? Have you checked Sitecore logs if there is anything there?

Comment: @MarekMusielak currently it's handled by the hosting provider. can i simulate this issue on IIS or some sitecore config so i can prove that this isn't an application issue?